# How to download new project file in Git?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

For example, in a project by another developer a new file was added.

By using TortoiseGit how can I download the file to your local repository?

Comment: voted to close: no research effort & quite general computer knowledge .. well I get SCMs are mainly for coding but .. there is a limit :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the changes from the remote repository.

See Tortoise documentation here:
https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html

In short:

Right click in directory. Choose TortoiseGit → Pull... .

Comment: but I deliberately deleted a file from a local repository, but after pull the file is not recovered. Already up-to-date.

Comment: You deleted the file locally and committed the changes?

Comment: if I do pull, the file can not be restored, however, commit -> master sees that the file does not exist

Comment: Do you delete file A and that "another" developer add file B?